# Passing object from spring controller to ANGULARJS

Tags: java, angularjs, jsp, spring-mvc, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to create a CRUD system on a list and I need to pass the list from the controller of spring to ANGULARJS controller. 
Can someone point to the right direction pls?
P.S: I already can receive the list and I can manipulate it in EL language

Comment: it maybe easier to answer you question, if you have a concrete question

Comment: Well I just need someone to point to the right direction

Comment: Maybe to make you understand, I need to send a list from spring controller and then receive in the jsp page with angularjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use some JSON necoding library and let it encode your objects when you return them from your controller. Jackson might help.

Comment: Thanks, so I need to set the response as Json in spring controller?

Comment: And while we're at it, can you tell me how to receive it in angularjs controller, cause it's driving me nuts

Comment: You need to define an object in terms of angular. Try this: https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/angular-model-objects-with-javascript-classes-2e6a067c73bc#.a94w36esa

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

I am an Angular developer and I work with a Spring Java team.

I believe they use Spring BOOT

http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/

Spring BOOT produces RESTful APIs and our Angular application makes HTTP requests to those APIs and Spring returns JSON responses.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but what I found was that if the Jackson api is set in the path, SPRING will detect it and it will parse the response as JSON automatically.